# Dos calendarios en la misma página

Tags: jquery, calendar

Necesito poner dos calendarios en la misma página pero solo se lanza uno de los dos. Necesito poner un calendario pequeño que me permita escoger fechas, estas fechas seleccionaran el calendario (agenda) grande.

Sé que el problema radica en el jQuery, pero no se como solucionarlo.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>

<head>
  <!-- MODAL !-->


  <!-- FIN MODAL !-->

  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='modules/calendario/cupertino/theme.css' />

  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='modules/calendario/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css' />
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='modules/calendario/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.print.css' media='print' />
  <script type='text/javascript' src='modules/calendario/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='modules/calendario/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js'></script>
  <!-- <script type='text/javascript' src='modules/calendario/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js'></script> !-->
  <script type='text/javascript' src='modules/calendario/fullcalendar/fullcalendar_v153_001.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='modules/calendario/fullcalendar/jquery.scrollTo-min.js'></script>

  <!--<script type='text/javascript' src='modules/calendario/qtip/jquery.qtip-1.0.0-rc3.min.js'></script>-->
  <script type='text/javascript' src='modules/calendario/qtip/jquery.qtip2.min.js'></script>
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='modules/calendario/qtip/jquery.qtip2.min.css' />
  <link href="extras/date-picker-v10/development-bundle/demos/demos.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="extras/date-picker-v10/development-bundle/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="extras/date-picker-v10/js/jquery.ui.datepicker-es.js"></script>


  <script languaje="javascript">
    function dias_entre_fecha(ano, mes, dia, anob, mesb, diab) {
      var miFecha = new Date(ano, mes - 1, dia);
      var laFecha = new Date(anob, mesb - 1, diab);
      var diferenciafechas = miFecha.getTime() - laFecha.getTime()
      var dias = Math.floor(diferenciafechas / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      return dias;
    }

    function abrir_ventana_datos_fiscales(txt, title, condicionesdiv) {
      txt = txt.replace(/_BARRSEPARACION_/g, "\"");
      return abrir_ventana(txt, title, condicionesdiv);
    }

    function elvalor_entero(num) {
      if (num == '')
        return 0;
      if (isNaN(num) == false)
        return parseInt(num, 10);
      else
        return 0;
    }

    function verificar_fechas() {
      var valor_fecha_inicial = document.form_buscar.fecha_desde.value.split("/");
      var valor_fecha_final = document.form_buscar.fecha_hasta.value.split("/");
      var dia1 = elvalor_entero(valor_fecha_inicial[0]);
      var mes1 = elvalor_entero(valor_fecha_inicial[1]);
      var ano1 = elvalor_entero(valor_fecha_inicial[2]);
      var dia2 = elvalor_entero(valor_fecha_final[0]);
      var mes2 = elvalor_entero(valor_fecha_final[1]);
      var ano2 = elvalor_entero(valor_fecha_final[2]);
      if (dia1 > 0 && dia1 < 32 && mes1 > 0 && mes1 < 13 && ano1 > 2000 && dia2 > 0 && dia2 < 32 && mes2 > 0 && mes2 < 13 && ano2 > 2000) {
        var entredias = dias_entre_fecha(ano2, mes2, dia2, ano1, mes1, dia1);

        if (entredias > -1) {
          var entrediashoy = dias_entre_fecha(anohoy, meshoy, diahoy, ano2, mes2, dia2);
          if (entrediashoy > -1)
            return true;
          else {
            alert("<?php echo _("
              La fecha final indicada no puede superar el dia de hoy "); ?>");
            return false;
          }
        } else {

          alert("<?php echo _("
            Las fecha inicial debe ser anterior a la final.
            "); ?>");
          return false;
        }
      } else {
        alert("<?php echo _("
          Debe indicar las fechas a filtrar correctamente.
          "); ?>");
        return false;
      }
    }
  </script>
  <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

      $('#fecha_desde').datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        minDate: new Date(2010, 0, 1),
        maxDate: "0",
        showButtonPanel: true
      });
      $('#fecha_hasta').datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        minDate: new Date(2010, 0, 1),
        maxDate: '+0D',
        showButtonPanel: true
      });

    });
  </script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    function mostrar_alerta(mensaje) {

      document.getElementById("busquedas_nadie2").innerHTML = "mensaje:" + mensaje;
    }

    function revalidar() {
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect')
    }

    function abrir_miventana(contenido, titulo, condic) {

      try {
        window.parent.abrir_miventana(contenido, titulo, condic);
      } catch (e) {
        alert("<?php echo _("
          error ");?>");
      }
    } <? php
    if ($_REQUEST[cerrado_ventana] == "Si") {
      echo "window.parent.cerrar_ventana_volatil();";
    } ?>




    $(document).ready(function() {



      $('#calendar').fullCalendar({


        /*eventAfterRender: function(event, element, view) {
                        $(element).css('width','10px');
                      },*/
        //width: 3000,
        //contentHeight: 1200,
        height: 750,
        viewDisplay: function(view) {
          //Se ejecuta despues de cargar el calendario.


          var scrollToHourMillis = 500; //tiempo de la animacion en milisegundos
          var viewName = view.name;

          if (viewName === "agendaWeek" || viewName === "agendaDay") {
            //alert(view.end.getMonth()+' '+view.end.getDate());
            var myDate = new Date(view.end.getFullYear(), view.end.getMonth(), view.end.getDate());
            myDate.setDate(view.end.getDate() - 1);
            mes_cargado = myDate.getMonth();
            ano_cargado = myDate.getFullYear();
            //alert('Dando'+myDate.getMonth()+' '+myDate.getDate());
            //ATENCION SI SE CAMBIA EL FORMATO DE 'timeFormat:' EL SIGUIENTE 'HH' TAMBIEN SE DEBE CAMBIAR
            var currentHour = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(new Date(), "HH");
            currentHour = ' ' + currentHour; //PARA NO BUSCAR EJ. 10:10AM 11:10AM y solo busque 10AM
            var $viewWrapper = $("div.fc-view-" + viewName + " div.scroll_slot");
            var currentHourLabel = $viewWrapper.find("table tbody tr th:contains('" + currentHour + "')");
            var hora_actual = $("div.fc-view-" + viewName + " div.scroll_slot th:contains('" + currentHour + "')").parent();
            $(hora_actual).find("td.fc-widget-content").addClass("div_hora_actual");
            $viewWrapper.animate({
              scrollTop: 0
            }, 0, function() {
              var targetOffset = currentHourLabel.offset().top - 70; //70 implica mostrar 60 minutos anteriores
              var scroll = targetOffset - $viewWrapper.offset().top - currentHourLabel.outerHeight();
              $viewWrapper.animate({
                scrollTop: scroll
              }, scrollToHourMillis);
            });
          } else {
            detitle = view.title.split(" ");
            var cargado_mes = false;
            if (detitle[1] > 0) ano_cargado = detitle[1];
            for (intmes = 0; intmes < 12; intmes++) {
              if (nombres_meses[intmes] == detitle[0]) {
                mes_cargado = intmes;
                cargado_mes = true;
              }
            }
            if (cargado_mes == false) {
              mes_cargado = view.visEnd.getMonth() - 1;
              if (mes_cargado < 0) mes_cargado = 0;
            }

          }
          document.getElementById('ano_indicado_usuario').value = ano_cargado;
          document.getElementById('cambiar_mes').value = mes_cargado;

        },
        header: {
          left: 'prev,next today',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        slotMinutes: 15,
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        allDayText: "DIARIOS",
        timeFormat: 'H:mm {- H:mm}' // default
          ,
        agenda: 'hh(:mm)TT', //H implica 24horas hh(:mm)TT
        axisFormat: 'HH:mm', // hh(:mm)TT
        <? php
        $consnoc = "select * from nocs_t where noc = '$noc'";
        $resnoc = mysql_query($consnoc) or die("La consulta fall&oacute;: $consnoc ".mysql_error());
        while ($linnoc = mysql_fetch_array($resnoc, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
          $hora_inicio_jornada = $linnoc['hora_inicio_jornada'];
          $hora_fin_jornada = $linnoc['hora_fin_jornada'];
          if ($hora_inicio_jornada != "" && $hora_inicio_jornada != "0:00" && $hora_inicio_jornada != "0:00") {
            echo "minTime: '$hora_inicio_jornada',\n ";
          }
          if ($hora_fin_jornada != "" && $hora_fin_jornada != "0:00" && $hora_fin_jornada != "00:00") {
            echo "maxTime: '$hora_fin_jornada',\n ";
          }
          //  minTime: 4,   maxTime: 20,
        }
        // hack en la linea 974 de fullcalendar.js donde cogemos la variable enviamos la variable
        // valor_select_filtro al json_eventos y la cogemos desde select_busquedas_nadie2
        //select_busquedas_nadie: document.getElementById("select_busquedas_nadie2").value
        //select_busquedas_nadie: $('#select_busquedas_nadie2').val()
        //select_busquedas_nadie: document.getElementById("select_busquedas_nadie2").value

        ?>
        events: {
            url: 'modules/calendario/json_eventos.php',
            cache: false,
            type: 'GET',
            allDay: false,
            data: {
              usuario_id: '<?php echo"$user_id"; ?>'

            },
            error: function() {
              alert('<?php echo _("Ha habido un error en la carga de registros!");?>');
            },
            color: 'blue', // a non-ajax option
            textColor: 'white' // a non-ajax option
          },
          firstHour: 7,
          selectable: true,
          selectHelper: true,
          select: function(start, end, allDay) { //CUANDO SE HACE CLICK EN LA AGENDA Crear nuevo registro
            var mes = start.getMonth() + 1;
            var tiempo = start.getHours() + ':' + start.getMinutes() + ':' + start.getSeconds();
            var fecha1 = start.getFullYear() + '-' + mes + '-' + start.getDate() + ' 00:00:00';

            var tiempofin = end.getHours() + ':' + end.getMinutes() + ':' + end.getSeconds();
            //var url_crear = 'modules.php?mod=inventada&file=form_nuevaentradaagenda2&accion=formcrear&user_id=<?= $user_id ?>&fecha=' + '&fecha=' + encodeURIComponent(fecha1) + '&hora=' + encodeURIComponent(tiempo)+ '&duracion=00:30:00'; // + encodeURIComponent(tiempo1);
            //$('#iframe_modal').attr('src',url_crear);
            //abrir_ventana('<iframe src=url_crear></iframe','AGENDA');
            <? php
            if ($_REQUEST[m] != '') {
              $para_informacion_url = "";
              if ($activado_modulo_planes_salud) {
                $para_informacion_url = "&informacion_planes_salud=$_REQUEST[informacion_planes_salud]";
              }

              if ($enventanita != "si") {

                $cons = "select clientes_t.nombre as nombre,clientes_t.id as cliente_id,mascotas_t.nombre as nombre_mascota from clientes_t left join mascotas_t on clientes_t.id=mascotas_t.cliente_id where mascotas_t.id = '$_REQUEST[m]'";
                $res = mysql_query($cons) or die("La consulta fall&oacute;: $cons ".mysql_error());
                while ($lin = mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
                  $nombre_empresa = $lin['nombre'];
                  $nombre_mascota = $lin['nombre_mascota'];
                }
                echo "abrir_miventana('<iframe src=modules.php?mod=inventada&file=form_nuevaentradaagenda&encarga=Si$para_informacion_url&decalendario=Si&fecha=' + encodeURIComponent(fecha1) + '&hora=' + encodeURIComponent(tiempo)+ '&hora_final=' + encodeURIComponent(tiempofin)+'&duracion=00:30:00&c=$_REQUEST[c]&m=$_REQUEST[m]&vetehab='+$(\"#buscar_algo\").val()+'&centro_id='+$(\"#id_centro\").val()+'&r=$_REQUEST[r]&enventanita=si  width=98% height=98% align=top style=\\'background-color:#FFFFFF;border:none\\' ></iframe>','"._("Crear cita para Cliente").
                " ".str_replace("'", "\\'", str_replace('"', '\\"', $nombre_empresa)).
                " "._("y algo").
                " ".str_replace("'", "\\'", str_replace('"', '\\"', $nombre_mascota)).
                "','height:560px; width:850px; background-color:white; overflow:auto');";
              } else {
                echo "window.location.href= 'modules.php?mod=inventada&file=form_nuevaentradaagenda&decalendario=Si$para_informacion_url&c=$_REQUEST[c]&m=$_REQUEST[m]&vetehab='+$(\"#buscar_algo\").val()+'&centro_id='+$(\"#id_centro\").val()+'&r=$_REQUEST[r]&enventanita=$enventanita&desde_historial=Si&user_id=$user_id&fecha=' + encodeURIComponent(fecha1) + '&hora=' + encodeURIComponent(tiempo)+ '&hora_final=' + encodeURIComponent(tiempofin)+'&duracion=00:30:00'; "; //// + encodeURIComponent(tiempo1);
              }
            } else {
              if ($enventanita != "si") {
                echo "abrir_miventana('<iframe src=modules.php?mod=inventada&file=form_especificarnuevaentradaagenda&encarga=Si&decalendario=Si&fecha=' + encodeURIComponent(fecha1) + '&hora=' + encodeURIComponent(tiempo)+ '&hora_final=' + encodeURIComponent(tiempofin)+'&duracion=00:30:00&vetehab='+$(\"#buscar_algo\").val()+'&motivo_consulta='+$(\"#motivo_consulta\").val()+'&centro_id='+$(\"#id_centro\").val()+'&r=$_REQUEST[r]&enventanita=si  width=98% height=98% align=top style=\\'background-color:#FFFFFF;border:none\\' ></iframe>','"._("Se indicara los datos para especificar una nueva cita en la agenda").
                "','height:560px; width:850px; background-color:white; overflow:auto');";
                //echo"abrir_miventana('<iframe src=modules.php?mod=inventada&file=form_especificarnuevaentradaagenda&encarga=Si&decalendario=Si&fecha=' + encodeURIComponent(fecha1) + '&hora=' + encodeURIComponent(tiempo)+ '&hora_final=' + encodeURIComponent(tiempofin)+'&duracion=00:30:00&vetehab='+$(\"#buscar_algo\").val()+'&motivo_consulta='+$(\"#motivo_consulta\").val+'&centro_id='+$(\"#id_centro\").val()+'&r=$_REQUEST[r]&enventanita=si  width=98% height=98% align=top style=\\'background-color:#FFFFFF;border:none\\' ></iframe>','"._("Se indicara los datos para especificar una nueva cita en la agenda")."','height:560px; width:850px; background-color:white; overflow:auto');";
              } else {
                echo "window.location.href= 'modules.php?mod=inventada&file=form_especificarnuevaentradaagenda&decalendario=Si&vetehab='+$(\"#buscar_algo\").val()+'&centro_id='+$(\"#id_centro\").val()+'&r=$_REQUEST[r]&enventanita=$enventanita&decalendario=Si&user_id=$user_id&fecha=' + encodeURIComponent(fecha1) + '&hora=' + encodeURIComponent(tiempo)+ '&hora_final=' + encodeURIComponent(tiempofin)+'&duracion=00:30:00'; ";
              }
            } ?>
            /*$('#basic-modal-content_boton_desde_agenda').modal({onClose: function(){
     $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );  
     $.modal.close();
    }});*/
          },
          eventDrop: function(event, delta) { //CUANDO SE MUEVE UN EVENTO Y SE DEJA EN LA NUEVA HORA
            var mes = event.start.getMonth() + 1;
            var tiempo = event.start.getHours() + ':' + event.start.getMinutes() + ':' + event.start.getSeconds();
            var fecha1 = event.start.getFullYear() + '-' + mes + '-' + event.start.getDate() + ' 00:00:00';
            var duracion = event.end.getHours() + ':' + event.end.getMinutes() + ':' + event.end.getSeconds();
            var url_actualizar = 'modules.php?mod=inventada&file=proceso_actualizar_evento_embebido&id=' + encodeURIComponent(event.id) + '&fecha=' + encodeURIComponent(fecha1) + '&hora=' + encodeURIComponent(tiempo) + '&duracion=' + encodeURIComponent(duracion);


            $('#calendar').append("<div style=display:none id='div_drop'></div>");
            $('#div_drop').load(url_actualizar, function() {
              $('#div_drop').remove();
              $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
              $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
            });
          },

          eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) { //CUANDO SE HACE CLICK EN UN EVENTO Modificar un registro

            var url_modificar = "";
            if (calEvent.title.indexOf('REUNION') != -1) {
              url_modificar = "";
            } else if (calEvent.title.indexOf('TAREA') != -1) {
              url_modificar = "";
            } else {
              url_modificar = 'modules.php?mod=inventada&file=form_modentradaagenda&enventanita=<?php echo"$enventanita";?>&user=<?php echo"$user_id"; ?>&accion=formmodificar&id=' + calEvent.id;
            } // del else
            <? php
            if ($enventanita != "si") {


              echo "abrir_miventana('<iframe src=modules.php?mod=inventada&file=form_modentradaagenda&encarga=Si&decalendario=Si&accion=formmodificar&id=' + calEvent.id+'&enventanita=si  width=98% height=98% align=top style=\\'background-color:#FFFFFF;border:none\\' ></iframe>','"._("Modificar cita").
              "  ','height:560px; width:850px; background-color:white; overflow:auto');";
            } else {
              echo "window.location.href= 'modules.php?mod=inventada&file=form_modentradaagenda&enventanita=$enventanita&decalendario=Si&user=$user_id&accion=formmodificar&id=' + calEvent.id; "; //// + encodeURIComponent(tiempo1);
            } ?>
            //$('#iframe_modal').attr('src',url_modificar);
            /*$('#basic-modal-content_boton_desde_agenda').modal({onClose: function(){
     $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );
     $.modal.close();
    }});*/

          },

          eventResize: function(event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, revertFunc) { //CUANDO CAMBIA DE TAMAÑO EL EVENTO
            var mes = event.start.getMonth() + 1;
            var tiempo = event.start.getHours() + ':' + event.start.getMinutes() + ':' + event.start.getSeconds();
            var fecha1 = event.start.getFullYear() + '-' + mes + '-' + event.start.getDate() + ' 00:00:00';
            var duracion = event.end.getHours() + ':' + event.end.getMinutes() + ':' + event.end.getSeconds();
            var url_actualizar = 'modules.php?mod=inventada&file=proceso_actualizar_evento_embebido&id=' + encodeURIComponent(event.id) + '&fecha=' + encodeURIComponent(fecha1) + '&hora=' + encodeURIComponent(tiempo) + '&duracion=' + encodeURIComponent(duracion);

            $('#calendar').append("<div style=display:none id='div_drop'></div>");
            $('#div_drop').load(url_actualizar, function() {
              $('#div_drop').remove();
              $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
              $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');

              //alert('hola');
              //$('#calendar').load('modules.php?mod=inventada&file=micalendario');
            });
          }, eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
            // var texto_divtime=element.find('div.fc-event-inner').text();
            //    if(texto_divtime!=null && texto_divtime!=""){
            //alert('Rendere divtime1: '+texto_divtime);
            //}
            var viewName = view.name;
            var viewstar_day = event.start.getDay();

            var position_my = 'top center';
            if (viewstar_day == 0 && viewName == "month") {
              position_my = 'top right';
            }
            if (viewstar_day == 1 && viewName == "month") {
              position_my = 'top left';
            }
            var color_contenido = "red";
            if (event.color_consulta != "") {
              color_contenido = event.color_consulta;
            }
            var texto_span = element.find('span.fc-event-title').text();
            //Para titulos...
            var para_titulo = event.title;
            // alert(para_titulo);
            para_titulo = para_titulo.replace(' - ' + event.nombre_consulta, ' <?php echo _("Motivo");?>: ' + event.nombre_consulta); //
            para_titulo_html = event.title.replace(' - ' + event.nombre_consulta, ' <br><label style="text-decoration:bold;color:black"><?php echo _("Motivo");?>:</label> ' + event.nombre_consulta);;
            para_titulo = para_titulo + ' <?php echo _("Usuario");?>: ' + event.nombre_usuario;
            para_titulo_html = '<label style="text-decoration: blink;color:black"><?php echo _("Evento");?>:</label>' + para_titulo_html + ' <br><label style="text-decoration:bold;color:black"><?php echo _("Usuario");?>:</label> ' + event.nombre_usuario;
            if (event.centro_descripcion != "") {
              para_titulo_html = para_titulo_html + ' <br><label style="text-decoration:bold;color:black"><?php echo _("Centro");?>:</label> ' + event.centro_descripcion;
            }
            if (event.descripcion != "") {
              para_titulo_html = para_titulo_html + ' <br><label style="text-decoration:bold;color:black"><?php echo _("Observaciones");?>:</label> ' + event.descripcion;
            }
            if (event.con_campana || event.si_vino == 1 || event.si_vino == 2) {
              if (event.con_campana) {
                para_titulo_html = para_titulo_html + ' <br><label style="text-decoration:bold;color:black"><?php echo _("Con Aviso");?></label> ';
              } else {
                if (event.si_vino == 1) {
                  para_titulo_html = para_titulo_html + ' <br><label style="text-decoration:bold;color:black"><?php echo _("Vino a consulta");?></label> ';
                } else {
                  para_titulo_html = para_titulo_html + ' <br><label style="text-decoration:bold;color:black"><?php echo _("No vino a consulta");?></label> ';
                }
              }
            } else {
              para_titulo_html = para_titulo_html + ' <br><label style="text-decoration:bold;color:black"><?php echo _("Sin Aviso");?></label> ';
            }
            //para_titulo_html='<span style="background: #FFFFCC;width:100%;height:100%">'+para_titulo_html+'</span>';

            element.qtip({

              //$("#consulta-layer"+event.id).qtip({  
              content: para_titulo_html,
              position: {
                my: position_my,
                at: 'bottom center'
              },
              style: {
                classes: 'qtip qtip-shadow',
                padding: 0,
                background: '#FFFFCC',

                textAlign: 'left',
                border: {
                  width: 1,
                  radius: 2,

                },
                show: 'mouseover',
                hide: 'mouseout',

                //tip: 'bottomLeft',
                name: 'cream' // And style it with the preset dark theme
              } // Give it a crea mstyle to make it stand out
            });






          },

          eventMouseover: function(event, domEvent, view) {
            var viewName = view.name;

            var layercampana = '';
            /* var es_nulo_contenido_layer=document.getElementById('campana-layer'+event.id);
   //   var es_nulo_contenido_layer_mensual=document.getElementById('campana-mensual-layer'+event.id);
         //alert('CONTENID LAYER'+es_nulo_contenido_layer);
         if(es_nulo_contenido_layer==null && viewName!="month"){
     var para_titulo=event.title;
      // alert(para_titulo);
       para_titulo=para_titulo.replace(' - '+event.nombre_consulta,' <?php echo _("motivo");?>: '+event.nombre_consulta);//
       para_titulo=para_titulo+' <?php echo _("Usuario:");?> '+event.nombre_usuario;
      // alert(para_titulo);
    if(event.con_campana){
      layercampana ='<div id="campana-layer'+event.id+'" class="fc-transparent" style="position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; top:-1px; text-align:right; z-index:120" title="'+para_titulo+'"><img src="images/bell2.png" id="edbut'+event.id+'" border="0" title="<?php echo _("Con envio de mensajes");?>" style="padding-right:5px; padding-top:2px;" /></div>';
      
    }else{
      layercampana ='<div id="campana-layer'+event.id+'" class="fc-transparent" style="position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; top:-1px; text-align:right; z-index:120" title="'+para_titulo+'"> </div>';
    }
    $(this).append(layercampana);
         }
    */
            var layer1 = '<div id="events-layer' + event.id + '" class="fc-transparent" style="position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; top:-1px; text-align:right; z-index:100"><a><img src="images/PNG22/edit22.png" title="editar" width="14" id="edbut' + event.id + '" border="0" style="padding-right:5px; padding-top:2px;" /></a>';
            var layer2 = '<a><img src="images/PNG22/delete22.png" title="borrar" width="14" id="delbut' + event.id + '" border="0" style="padding-right:5px; padding-top:2px;" /></a>';
            var layer3 = '</div>';

            if (!event.borrar) {
              layer2 = '';
            }

            //var layer = layer1 + layer2 + layer3;
            //$(this).append(layer);

          },
          eventMouseout: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
            //$("#events-layer"+event.id+"").hide();
            /*var es_nulo_contenido_layer=document.getElementById('campana-layer'+event.id);
     
 if(es_nulo_contenido_layer!=null ){
   $("#campana-layer"+event.id+"").remove();
 }*/
          },

          loading: function(bool) {
            if (bool) $('#loading').show();
            else $('#loading').hide();

          }

      });

      //$('#busquedas_nadie').html('Visualizar: <select onchange="$(\'#calendar\').fullCalendar(\'refetchEvents\');" id=select_busquedas_nadie2><option value=1>Todo</option><option value=2>Mis tareas planificadas</option><option value=3>Mis Reuniones</option><option value=4>Solo los eventos que yo he compartido</option><option value=5>Solo los eventos que me han compartido</option></select>');  

    });
  </script>
  <table width='100px'>
    <tr>
      <td width='100px'>
        <input id='fecha_desde' class='form-control' style='width:50px;display:inline;padding:6px 12px;text-align:center;height:34px;' value='$fecha_desde' maxlength='10' size='10' name='fecha_desde'>

        <i class='fa fa-arrows-h' style='font-size:20px;' style='width:39px;display:inline;padding:6px 12px;height:34px;'></i> 
        <!--<input id='txt_separador' class='form-control' style='width:39px;display:inline;padding:6px 12px;text-align:center;height:34px;' value='a' maxlength='10' size='10' name='txt_separador' readonly>-->

        <input id='fecha_hasta' style='width:50px;display:inline;padding:6px 12px;text-align:center;height:34px;' class='form-control' value='$fecha_hasta' maxlength='10' size='10' name='fecha_hasta'>";
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <div id="calendar" class="has-toolbar"></div>
```

Uno de los calendarios se llama mediante iframe como se puede apreciar.

¿Existe alguna manera de que se puedan utilizar los dos?

Comment: Deberías de tener dos calendarios con dos id diferentes.

Comment: tienes razon. He añadido como llamo a los calendarios.

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrarnos un [mcve](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Si te fijas, tu código no funciona tal y como lo has publicado (pulsa en `Ejecutar` y lo verás) así que nos dificulta poder reproducir el problema con la cantidad de fuentes externas que usas.

Comment: Apreciado Oscar disculpa el retraso. Estaba viviendo :) te lo pongo ya.

Comment: He tratado de reproducir el problema que sufres y a mí me funciona con un [mcve que me he creado aquí](http://codepen.io/OscarGarcia/pen/mOjbvz).

Comment: Apreciado Oscar, antes que nada agradecerte la respuesta, lo miro y te comento algo.

Comment: Oscar he revisado tu propuesta de respuesta, pero solo ejecuta un calendario. Si nos fijamos en el codigo se hacen dos llamadas a dos calendarios diferentes. Uno 'fullcalendar' y otro 'date-picker-v10' que este ultimo arranque, tal y como muestras es sencillo y se consigue. Pero que funcionen los dos a la vez... ahi esta el problema. Intentando aportar mas info: el datepicker ya lo conoces y lo lanzas sin problemas, el segundo calendario es este: https://fullcalendar.io/ y esta integrado en la pagina web donde debo arrancar el datepicker. No lo ves en el codigo, porque no funcionan juntos.

Answer (score 1):

Solo coloca más DatePicker con los IDS que necesitas.

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {    

       $('#fecha_desde').datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear:true,
        minDate: new Date(2010,0,1),
        maxDate: "0",
        showButtonPanel: true});
        $('#fecha_hasta').datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear:true,
        minDate: new Date(2010,0,1),
        maxDate: '+0D',
        showButtonPanel: true});

    $('#fecha_hasta').datepicker({  //suponiendo que necesitas lo mismo
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear:true,
        minDate: new Date(2010,0,1),
        maxDate: "0",
        showButtonPanel: true});
        $('#fecha_hasta').datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear:true,
        minDate: new Date(2010,0,1),
        maxDate: '+0D',
        showButtonPanel: true});
    });
```